# Question regarding user enrollment using Fabric-CA node sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have created my fabric network which includes 2 Orgs having 2 peers each and used Fabric-CA for generating crypto material for peers and orderer.

how to enroll and register users which will do the transactions (invoke/query the ledger) using Fabric-CA node sdk? I have gone through the "balance-transfer" sample app but in that sample, key-store path for storing user credentials is hard-coded and keys gets generated inside the project directory.

I assume, there will be some way possible to enroll users and store their credentials inside the peer containers of organization(as other peer related certificates/keys are also getting stored inside the container of the peer).

let me know if my assumption is correct or wrong. If correct, then how to achieve this using fabric-ca node sdk. Else how to store user credentials outside the containers securely. One way can be maybe using HSM?

Comment: As far as I know, fabric does not store the credentials for obvious security issues. I would mean that anyone being able to connect to the peer could use that identity. You don't want that. You want people to prove who they are and then do stuff.  I have a sample code that register a new user and stores it to your local "crypto store". I don't know if that is what you are looking for. Just let me know.